# Wazuh Indexder throws /entrypoint.sh permission denied after running `docker-compose up`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permissions, lxc, proxmox

I am setting up a Wazuh LXC container on proxmox by refering the [Wazuh Official](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/deployment-options/docker/wazuh-container.html) documentation:

My Debian LXC:
`Linux debian-wazuh 6.2.16-3-pve #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC PVE 6.2.16-3 (2023-06-17T05:58Z) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Here's a [link](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-docker/blob/4.5.3/single-node/docker-compose.yml) to the docker-compose.yml file

When I try to run `docker-compose up -d` the following error is thrown:

```
single-node_wazuh.manager_1 is up-to-date
Recreating single-node_wazuh.indexer_1 ... error

ERROR: for single-node_wazuh.indexer_1  Cannot start service wazuh.indexer: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec /entrypoint.sh: permission denied: unknown

ERROR: for wazuh.indexer  Cannot start service wazuh.indexer: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec /entrypoint.sh: permission denied: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

An [unresolved issue](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-docker/issues/790) could be found on gh/wazuh-docker, however, I am not using Openshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker-compose link that you have shared belongs to version 4.5.3, this version is still under development so you should use the latest productive tag available, which according to the documentation is v4.5.2, please use the correct version and check if the problem still occurs

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Proxmox does not recommend running Docker inside another LXC container, see [Proxmox forum post](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/trying-to-run-docker-inside-lxc-container.67368/) and refers to the use of a VM: **using docker on lxc isn't recommended. it requires too many workarounds to function. just use a VM**